# Why do SXSSF hyperlink show as 0 in excel but contains cell data compared to XSSF on apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, hyperlink, apache-poi

I am using Apache poi 3.11 and tried using SXSSF (for memory efficiency) format to create my excel file (xlxs) but my hyperlink cells are display as 0 instead of the hyperlink text, Originally I was using XSSF format but I do not encounter this problem.

I tried using XSSF back and it resolved my problem but it isn't memory efficient enough for my use case

Comment: Apache POI 3.11 is too old to discuss about. Please use a more current version.

Comment: [Apache POI 3.11 was released in 2014](https://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.11), what happens if you upgrade to something that isn't 9 years old?